# Is there a way to add an image to a MessageBox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox, userform

I am wondering if it is possible to add an image to a messagebox in VBA mainly, but if not any other languages.

```
MsgReply = MsgBox("InspectionCreator - Continue?", vbMsgBoxSetForeground + vbSystemModal + vbYesNo)
If vbYes = MsgReply Then
Listener.Connect2SW
Else: End
End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't display an image in a MessageBox. Unless you mean the symbols such as Warning, Error, etc?

Although you could simulate it by creating a UserForm which has the *appearance* of a MessageBox, with an image in the background and then just `Show()` the form instead of calling the MsgBox function.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought, but just thought I would check Thanks.